# Determine if ASP.NET Sessions are enabled

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

What is the best way to do a boolean test in C# to determine if ASP.NET sessions are enabled?  I don't want to use a try-catch block and Sessions != null throws an Exception.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this(Pseudo code)

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.Load("Web.Config"); 

XmlNode pagesenableSessionState = document.SelectSingleNode("//Settings[@Name = 'pages']/Setting[@key='enableSessionState']");

if(pagesenableSessionState .Attributes["value"].Value =="true)
{
//Sessions are enabled
}
else
{
//Sessions are not enabled
}
```

Comment: Since session state can also be enabled with a page directive and in other configuration files (machine.config or web.config at a higher directory level), this answer is at least incomplete and at worst plain wrong.

Answer (score 7):

You will not get an exception if you use `HttpContext.Current`:

```
if(HttpContext.Current.Session != null)
{
    // Session!
}
```

Comment: This works very well and does not throw exception. I don't know why @KeithAdler says it's throwing exception.

Comment: `Page.Session` throws an exception, but `HttpContext.Session` does not.

Comment: I am definitely seeing "if (HttpContext.Session != null)" throw exceptions when sessions aren't enabled in dot net 6:

System.InvalidOperationException: Session has not been configured for this application or request

Comment: Added a new answer below. Using HttpContext.Features.Get<ISessionFeature>()?.Session != null is a solution for newer dot net versions.

Answer (score 2):

You want to interrogate the [EnableSessionState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.pagessection.enablesessionstate.aspx) property in `Web.config`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can determine if session state is enabled:

```
PagesSection pagesSection = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/pages") as PagesSection;

if ((null != pagesSection) && (pagesSection.EnableSessionState == PagesEnableSessionState.True))
    // Session state is enabled
else
    // Session state is disabled (or readonly)
```

Answer (score 1):

For dot net 6 you can use:

```
if (HttpContext.Features.Get<ISessionFeature>()?.Session != null)
{
}
```